# JPA Params with nativeQuery in Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a custom @Query in a repository:

```
    @Query(value = "select CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '?1 days'", nativeQuery = true)
public List<OrderEntity> getOrders(Integer numDays);
```

I want to add param in '?1 days' for example

getOrders(5) -> select CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '5 days'

But it doesn't work, not filter.

How can I write this query so that it works with JPA?

Comment: Try `... - (? || ' days')::interval`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's a one solution. It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
select CURRENT_DATE - ?1 * INTERVAL '1 day'
```